# how to print graphic mode in esc pos flutter

Tags: flutter

I using [flutter_esc_pos_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_esc_pos_utils)
I tried to print a 567x148 image. However, printing using image printing mode produces a very different quality from reality. So I tried

```
  bytes += generator.imageRaster(
        tmp,
        align: PosAlign.left,
        imageFn: PosImageFn.graphics
      );
```

However it doesn't work

The problem starts from the function _toRasterFormat(image);

```
 List<int> _toRasterFormat(Image imgSrc) {
    final Image image = Image.from(imgSrc); // make a copy
    final int widthPx = image.width;
    final int heightPx = image.height;

    grayscale(image);
    invert(image);

    // R/G/B channels are same -> keep only one channel
    final List<int> oneChannelBytes = [];
    final List<int> buffer = image.getBytes(order: ChannelOrder.rgba);
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += 4) {
      oneChannelBytes.add(buffer[i]);
    }

    // Add some empty pixels at the end of each line (to make the width divisible by 8)
    if (widthPx % 8 != 0) {
      final targetWidth = (widthPx + 8) - (widthPx % 8);
      final missingPx = targetWidth - widthPx;
      final extra = Uint8List(missingPx);
      for (int i = 0; i < heightPx; i++) {
        final pos = (i * widthPx + widthPx) + i * missingPx;
        ////error at here:
        ////Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..8459: 8460
        oneChannelBytes.insertAll(pos, extra);
      }
    }
```